# Intellij not showing project folders (Python project)

Tags: python, intellij-idea

This crops up from time to time.  One day when I open Intellij my directory listing of the files are all gone and I just see the top level.
[image]

I see answers for this question for Java but I'm not using Java for anything.  Is there any way to fix this besides deleting the .idea/ folder and setting all my preferences again?

Comment: try the "invalidate cache/restart"?

Comment: Don't you keep your project under OneDrive folder?

Comment: I don't keep folders on remote mounted folders like OneDrive, NFS or google docs.  I tried the invalidate Cache/restart and that gets rid of my conda environment list.  I did find out what is causing this.  There was a time in the project where I didn't have .idea in the .gitignore file so when I clear out those files I revert the project back to an earlier state.  I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I noticed this as well and I don't use Python. I can agree that the only solution I found was

1. Close Intellij.
2. Delete .idea folder
3. Open project folder again.

Unfortunately in this case we loose our specific project settings.

One thing for Python is that you need to have a python plugin for Intellij IDEA and I noticed that PyCharm works a little bit better (I guess because it is designed for Python). Maybe you could try to change to PyCharm and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm trying this out.  Thanks.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I haven't hit this problem in PyCharm.